# Do I need multiple run configurations - one per Python file - in Pycharm even though the only difference between them is the script?

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm

I created a Python project in Pycharm which contains multiple Python files. As of just now, I need to create a run configuration for each Python file in my project, even though they're all the exact same - with the exception of the script.

This seems unnecessary and laborious and I would love to just use one run configuration for multiple Python files.

That said, I'm a novice Python programmer just getting started and so still unfamiliar with large parts of the language.

My Project Files:

[image]

My Run Configuration - Used for all Python files:

[image]

**Some Research Carried Out**

I've searched for a solution and explanation to this, but have been unable to find anything. Some of the places I've tried:

- JetBrainsTV on youtube (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JLfd9LOdu_U)
- JetBrains Website (https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/run-debug-configuration-python.html)
- Stack Overflow

I hope there is sufficient detail here, if not I'd be happy to elaborate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If those files are independent and you have nothing specific to them, then I see two simple ways of running them:

1. You don't have to manually create a run configuration for every file. You can just Right-Click on the file in the project tree and click "Run "

[image: Running from the context menu]

2. You can use the Terminal and run them files using the python interpreter as needed.

[image]

Comment: That sequentially creates a config for each python file you run/debug in that manner with.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a similar situation when I started competitive programming. In my case I wanted to redirect my Test Cases from an `input.txt` file rather than manually typing the test cases for every run of my code. Using the above solution was not feasible, as I would need to manually change the `Script` Path and `Redirect Input` path in the **Run Configuration** window for every script I was running.

So what I wanted was, one run configuration, that would run all the scripts with `Redirect Input` path being set to `input.txt`.

To do that,

1. I created a `main.py` file with the following content:

   ```
    import sys

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        fname = sys.argv[1]
        exec(open(fname).read())
   ```

   This `main.py` file is going to run my other python scripts.
2. Created [this run configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jsc5X.png) for the `main.py` file.

Now, every time I needed to run any code, with the code window open, ran this configuration, which actually executed `main.py` with current file name passed as its argument, which would then also take the inputs redirected from `input.txt`.

Hope this helps you or anyone trying to run multiple python scripts with a single run configuration in `PyCharm`.